# Django Rest Framework: can't get user id from given token

Tags: django, python-3.x, postgresql, django-rest-framework

I'm dealing with my first Django project. I'm trying to create an api that accepts a token via post request and queries the public_authtoken_token table for the related user id.

The dbms I'm using is PostgreSQL 10.6. Django version is 2.1.1 and DRF is 3.8.2

Here's the "view" code I have:

```
from rest_framework.authtoken.models import Token
from rest_framework.views import APIView

class MyView(APIView):

    def post(self, request, format=None):

        my_token = request.META.get('HTTP_AUTHORIZATION')
        user_id = Token.objects.get(key=my_token).user_id
        return Response(status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

My problem is that I'm getting the following exception when I do

`user_id = Token.objects.get(key=http_token).user_id` :

```
rest_framework.authtoken.models.Token.DoesNotExist: Token matching query does not exist.
```

Now,I have verified that the tokens I used to test it are in the db and they have a valid user_id. Also, I verified that the token I read from the HTTP request is correct as well.
Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: With `request.META.get('HTTP_AUTHORIZATION')` your probably get a string such as `Token YoUrToKeN`. You need to split this string and extract token.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you debug and see the value that you are retrieving with `request.META.get('HTTP_AUTHORIZATION')`, you will notice that it's something like this:

```
JWT eyJhbGciOiAiSFMyNTYiLCAidHlwIj
```

that value and prefix will be different based on your authentication backend for django rest. But you can simply fix this bug with code below:

```
from rest_framework.authtoken.models import Token
from rest_framework.views import APIView

class MyView(APIView):

    def post(self, request, format=None):
        my_token = request.META.get('HTTP_AUTHORIZATION').split()[1]
        user_id = Token.objects.get(key=my_token).user_id
        return Response(status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I figured the error came about because the token is not created prior. Swapping `.get` to `.get_or_create` got it to work.